# Can you expand my half solution for a specific problem in c?

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, while-loop, printf

Input:

Enter the number of rows: 5

Expected Output:

```
     1
    121    
   12321
  1234321
 123454321
```

I am trying to solve that problem by following the below approach->

Approach:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
//Declaring variables for storing information
int num_rows,value=1,p=1,t=1,f=1;

//prompting and taking input from the user
printf("Please enter the number of row: ");
scanf("%d",&num_rows);

for(int i=1; i<=num_rows; i++){

    for(int m=1; m<=num_rows-i; m++){
        printf(" ");
    }
    for(int j=1; j<=p; j++){
            //Condition to display the value as 1 for the first iteration as well as each of the row's first position

            if(i==1 || j==1){
                value=1;
            }
            //Condition to display the value as 1 for each of the row's last position
         else if(i==t && j==f){
            
            value=1;

         }

          else{
            //This is for displaying value within first and last value of each row

             value=value+1;




            }
        printf("%d",value);
    }
    t++;
    f=f+2;


    printf("\n");
    p=p+2;
}
 }
```

Now my problem is: Output shows like

```
       1
      121
     12341
    1234561
   123456781
```

By the above code, I can show the value one as the first and last position of each of the single row. But I could not complete the pattern of the middle position's value within the first and last position of each row. There is a ton of solutions that exist online for this particular problem. But I want to find out the solution only by myself. That's why I am here to take some suggestions from you.Thank you in advance

Comment: OK, so you'll either need to compute value from the position you're printing, or if you want to increase and decrease `value` as you're doing then you'll need to switch from `value=value+1` (which can be written as `++value` or `value++` too) to `value=value-1`. What's the logic you need to decide increment or decrement? Can you implement that?

Comment: I wanted to decide increment. I am trying. @Rup

Comment: I don’t understand the problem. If the “number of rows” input is more than one digit, what should the bottom row look like? If I enter 11, should the output end with 123456789101110987654321? Or is 9 the maximum allowed?

Comment: Nine is not the maximum allowed. if you enter 11 the output will end with 123456789101110987654321.@Howlium

Comment: OK: the middle element in your line is going to be the `i`th. So if j <= i then you need to increase value, and if j > i then you need to decrease value instead.

Comment: "I want to find out the solution only by myself" - then why are you asking us to do it for you? Be careful @Rup, this smells like a university assignment that we are being asked to complete on the asker's behalf.

Comment: @IanKemp Sir, I updated my statements. You can check it. Now, you can take back the downvote.Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is My solution to the Problem.
I have taken row we are printing as benchmark to note the middle value of the row being printed. The max value will be same as the row i.e. First row will have 1 as highest, second having 2 and so on. So for your "could not complete the pattern of the middle position's value" is this. Start with 1 and go to the row value as max, and decrement from there.

An implementation of same is below.

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main() {
   int i, space, rows,j;


   printf("Enter the number of rows: ");
   scanf("%d", &rows);


   for (i = 1; i <= rows; ++i) {
      for (space = 1; space <= rows - i; ++space) {
         printf(" ");
   
      }
//Using the row we on as the benchmark for the values we need to go to
      for(j=1;j<i;j++)
         printf("%d",j);
//Handling the case of first row
      if(i==1){
         printf("1\n");
         continue;
      }
//Printing the Decrement
      for(;j>=1;j--)
         printf("%d",j);
      printf("\n");
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your facilitiation.@Mohit Sharma

Comment: No worries. If noticed you had spaces figured out, so I didn't explain on that. ( if you happy with solution, you mayaccept the answer)

Comment: Ok, I have already stayed with the solution. But I will give one more try with your solution . Thank you. @Mohit Sharma

Answer (score 0):

Your solution with if-else statements is too complicated.

For example this loop

```
for(int j=1; j<=p; j++){
```

when the condition

```
j<=p
```

is changed within the loop due to this statement

```
p=p+2;
```

makes the program unreadable.

I can suggest a simpler solution.

Here you are.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    const unsigned int UPPER_BOUND = 10;
    
    while ( 1 )
    {
        printf( "Please enter the number of rows less than %u (0 - exit): ", UPPER_BOUND );
        
        unsigned int n;
        
        if ( scanf( "%u", &n ) != 1 || n == 0 ) break;
        
        if ( !( n < UPPER_BOUND ) ) n = UPPER_BOUND - 1;
        
        putchar( '\n' );

        for ( unsigned int i = 0; i < n; i++ )
        {
            unsigned int value = 1;
            
            printf( "%*u", n - i, value );
            while ( value != i + 1 ) printf( "%u", ++value );
            while ( --value != 0 ) printf( "%u", value );
            
            putchar( '\n' );
        }

        putchar( '\n' );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The program output might look like
'

```
Please enter the number of rows less than 10 (0 - exit): 5

    1
   121
  12321
 1234321
123454321

Please enter the number of rows less than 10 (0 - exit): 10

        1
       121
      12321
     1234321
    123454321
   12345654321
  1234567654321
 123456787654321
12345678987654321

Please enter the number of rows less than 10 (0 - exit): 0
```

Comment: Sir, I got it. Thank you for your facilitiation. @Vlad from Moscow